# Android Notification Action

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I try to use local notification and it's actions. I want to create a notification and handle multiple action types. My notification asks a question to the user. There are two options, yes or no. My implementation is below:

```
Intent yesReceive = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
yesReceive.setAction("YES");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, CODE, yesReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.icon1, "Yes", pendingIntent);
```

It recreates the activity. But old activity already alive. When I press back button, I can see it. How can I replace the new activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "finish()" to close down the activity before you move onto the next one.

Here is a simple example:

startActivity(intent); <- here I am telling the program to start the desired actitvity

finish(); <- Here I am asking the program to close the current activity before I move onto the next one.

`Intent yesReceive = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
yesReceive.setAction("YES");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, CODE, yesReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.icon1, "Yes", pendingIntent);
finish();`

Comment: This code finishes current activity and creates a notification. But my problem is that I notify a notification and if I press yes button, it create an activity and there are many instances of same activity class at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with below line

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not a solution. Because it causes to miss extras of the intent on restart.